# I want to use loop to make radio button as many as in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to make sets of buttons as many as the number of rooms
So I used a map to make radio button sets
If it works there should be 4 sets of buttons.

but it doesn't work
please help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import RadioForm, {
  RadioButton,
  RadioButtonInput,
  RadioButtonLabel
} from "react-native-simple-radio-button";

const temp_data = {
  room1: 0.1,
  room2: 0.2,
  room3: 0.3,
  room4: 0.4
};

var radio_props = [{ label: "10%", value: 0 }, { label: "30%", value: 1 }];

export default class TaskSetting extends Component {
  render() {
    var tem1 = Object.keys(temp_data).map(num => {
      return;
      <RadioForm
        radio_props={radio_props}
        initial={0}
        onPress={value => {
          this.setState({ value: value });
        }}
      />;
    });
    return <View>{tem1}</View>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `=> {}`, you need to add `return <YourComponent />` inside `{}`,

or you can choose not to use `{}` and directly `=> <YourComponent />`

```
export default class TaskSetting extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {Object.keys(temp_data).map(num =>
          <RadioForm
            radio_props={radio_props}
            initial={0}
            onPress={value => {
              this.setState({ value: value });
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Check it online:

[image: Edit async-glade-vrkcr]